# Extract content with PHP Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

i'm trying to extract "XXXXXXX" with PHP Simple HTML DOM description

`<h2 class="title"><a href="/videos/96283/live-stream/">XXXXXXX</a></h2>`

I tried

```
$ret = $html->find('h2[class="title"]') ;
```

but i don't know the next instruction because there is no attribute. How i can do this ?

I need to extract also "XX" from this code, i think it's the same problem no ?

`<a id="likeScore" appName='videos' object="video" objectid="96" direction="up" class="button like  icon-heart youLike not-active">XX</a>`

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one I think this could work:

```
$text = $html->find('h2[class="title"] a',0)->innertext;
```

For tags with ID you can use something more direct:

```
$text1 = $html->getElementById("likeScore")->innertext;
```

or using the #selector syntax

```
$text1 = $html->find('#likeScore',0)->innertext;
```

Documentation:

https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm#section_access